# Better way to read Laravel (PHP) Logs

Tags: laravel, logging

I have an Laravel application hosted on Third Party Server. The application is in production and produces many PHP Errors daily based on how users are using it.

I want a better way to read the laravel.log file, instead of doing SSH into the Server and reading it through VIM.

Please advice on what are some other better way to read errors on log file.

Comment: @HoboSapiens agree, the software was made by someone else, and now I am incharge of it, I want to fix the issues User's are facing in live software first.

Comment: Why not setup a simple web access interface (with secure access) that just returns the contents of log file in the browser? (you should have access to the Laravel logs that are in `storage`).

Comment: @user1864610 you know, to fix the errors you don't write *many more* code, you try to read and understand where's the error coming from. For that you need the best tools, and so the question is very valid and doesn't deserve this criticism (nor the negative feedback).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this package https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer

I am using it in my project and it's rather useful.

Comment: This changed my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a better way but it depends on the requirement if only query logs or any such small errors has to be checked then Laravel logs are all logged in \storage\logs\Laravel.log
You can empty this file and reload the website all the errors will be populated here again.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Log Reader** package so simple and easy installation. It also provides JSON API also, so that you can make your own UI if want.

GitHub: https://github.com/haruncpi/laravel-log-reader

[image: Laravel Log Reader Preview]